# Approach to solving this ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+\sin y+x\cos y+x = 0$$
This equation looks like a linear ordinary differential equation of first order, but it is not (for the appearance of $\sin y$ and $\cos y$). So I want to find a way of variable substitution to transform this one into a solvable linear ordinary differential equation.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to suspect that a symbolic solution exists? Most ODE do not have such a solution, and most modifications of equations with a symbolic solution will render it unsolvable in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If you switch variables, the equation becomes
$$\frac 1{x'}+\sin (y)+x(1+\cos (y)) = 0$$ which does not seem to be too bad (at least for the homogeneous part). In the worst case, use the integrating factor.

More than likely, it could be difficult to inverse the solution but who knows ?

**Edit**

Reading @Eli Bartlett's answer, the problem is in fact very simple
$$y'+\sin (y)+x\cos (y)+x = 0$$ Using the tangent half-angle substitution
$$y=2 \tan ^{-1}(z) \quad \implies \quad \frac{2 \left(z'+z+x\right)}{z^2+1}=0$$

$$z=1-x+c_1\,e^{-x}\quad \implies \quad \color{red}{y=2 \tan ^{-1}\left(1-x+c_1 e^{-x}\right)}$$

Comment: I've tried this before, but it still did not work. And I'm wondering about the form of integrating factor( but u(x) is apparently not helpful, either).

Comment: @xinyi. I have a possible idea that I shall try tomorrow morning

Comment: @xinyi. Look at the edit !

Comment: A much neater solution (+1)

Comment: bravo! So clear and concise!

Comment: @xinyi. I think that, in 80 years, it is the first time I use the tangent half-angle substitution for solving a differential equation. Thanks & cheers. :-)

Comment: Thanks, too! It's cheerful to see someone who has been enthusiastic all the time about math for so many years! I've got great strength from that.  :-)

Comment: @xinyi. When I found this solution, just as Snoopy, I told my wife : *"You know what ? I am happy !"* . Thanks for the nice words & cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Per Claude Leibovici, we’ll switch variables
\begin{align}
(\sin(y)+(1+\cos(y))x)x’_y+1=0.
\end{align}
Taking $x=u-\sin(y)/(1+\cos(y))$ we arrive at the separable equation
\begin{align}
(1+\cos(y))uu’=u-1,\quad \longrightarrow\quad
u+\log(u-1)+\tan(y/2)=c.
\end{align}
Upon substituting original variables our solution comes to
\begin{align}
x+\frac{\sin(y)}{1+\cos(y)}+\log\left(x+\frac{\sin(y)}{1+\cos(y)}-1\right)+\tan\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)=c
\end{align}

Comment: You inspired me ! Thanks and (+1). Cheers :-)